# Select unicode filename in Bash

Tags: bash, filenames, autocomplete

Ok; suppose I'm in Bash and I have several files in a folder.  Several of them are named `file☠☡☢☣.txt`, where `☠☡☢☣` starts with crazy untypable unicode characters.  How would I refer to one of them?  Pushing tab only auto-completes to `file`, and then it wants you to type a crazy character.  Is there some way to tell bash "select the 3rd one in that list you just gave me"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you work around it and use another type of key binding with readline, such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.
Add the following to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[Z": menu-complete
```

Then issue an `exec bash` (this should then read the settings in your `~/.inputrc`). As a one-off, instead of restarting bash, you can set up the same binding by running `bind '"\e[Z": menu-complete'`.

You should now be able to use repeated <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> sequences to cycle through the filenames that match (rather than having to input the next matching character). This will work for any command issued (as it's a standard read-line command that is being bound to the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> sequence). 
As noted by the OP, this does not effect the standard behavior of the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, it just adds the functionality of the  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> combo.

Comment: edited to mention the use of `exec bash`, as that's quite an important step to make it work! ;)

Comment: Thanks!  For anyone who's wondering, this doesn't seem to change the normal functionality; it just adds the shift-tab key combo.

Comment: Correct, please leave my tab key alone!! :) I'd be upset if that changed :D

Answer (score 3):

Another way that works sometimes is to use `?` or `*` globbing wildcards and then typing some of the remainder of "stuff" until you get a unique match with tab completion.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the directory containing `file☠☡☢☣.txt` and enter `ls -i`.   You will see the line:

```
xxxxx file☠☡☢☣.txt
```

where `xxxxx` is the index number of `file☠☡☢☣.txt`.   Enter:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -inum xxxxx -exec /bin/mv -i {} bettername.txt \;
```

where `xxxxx` on the preceding line is the aforementioned index number obtained from `ls -i`.   This renames `file☠☡☢☣.txt` as `bettername.txt`.